# Angular ngx-boostrap datepicker position issue on mobile screen

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

ngx-bootstrap/datepicker is working fine when larger screen but not in mobile screens. Need help.

[image]

But when I reduce the screen size to mobile (also on actual mobile devices), it opens in wrong position.

[image]

ngx-bootstrap/datepicker version 5.3.2

"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",

This is how I am using that in the template.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-6 form-group">
    <input type="text"
    class="form-control"
    style="cursor: pointer"
    readonly="true"
    [minDate]="minDate"
    [maxDate]="dt"
    #dp="bsDatepicker"
    bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue"
    (bsValueChange)="UpdateDashboard()">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd use html 5 grid and set justify items to center. Ot attach left margin.

Comment: I tried style="cursor: pointer;justify-items: center;margin-left: auto;" but same thing. Can you please elaborate on what changes should i do?

Comment: Display must be grid. Open the web page press f12 and locate element, then you can test the style you want there.

Comment: <bs-datepicker-container aria-label="calendar" class="bottom ng-tns-c9-3 ng-star-inserted" role="dialog" style="display: block; position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(68px, 133px, 0px);"> I found this part is causing the problem. If I remove transform: translate then it works. However, it's part of ngx-bootstrap/datepicker

Comment: I couldn’t figure out how to solve it yet.

Comment: hello @DhavalChokshi any update on this one, appreciate for any help. facing same kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the view on mobile by adding the below css for screen-sizes less than 600px;

```
   @media screen and (max-width:600px){
       ::ng-deep bs-datepicker-container{
           transform: translate3d(0px, 647px, 0px)!important;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this css and set the adaptivePosition property to false. My problem fixed.

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    bs-datepicker-container{
        position: fixed !important;
        transform: translate3d(10px, 240px, 0px)!important;
    }
 }
```